# Asp.net Configuration Error(crystal report error)

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports, web-config

i friend developed project and sent me the code while running the application i am getting this error.
please check the screenshot
I am using visual studio 2012.
[image: Error Image]

Comment: If this assembly is not needed, then remove the configuration line. If it is needed, then figure out what file it needs and put it on the server.

Comment: ok i can remove it..may be then it will work , is there any good solution for this?

Comment: Any good solution for what? Removing it? Open the web.config file, delete line 50 and see if it works. Keep a backup copy of the web.config file in case it breaks things. That's where source code control comes in handy.